# How should you keep Azure Resource Manager JSON consistent with Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment, azureportal

If you modify a resource through the Azure Portal, you may forget to update your ARM JSON before your next deployment and this would lead to an outdated deployment.

Also, if you have system admins taking care of your Azure Portal and your developers keeping track of ARM JSON in the source control, you need a good way to make sure to keep the environments consistent.

What would be the best practise to do that?

Answer (score 3):

That's an easy question, don't modify anything through the portal. Or follow the change process as described by ITIL, or invent your own wheel.

But apart from that, there is no answer, there is no way your repository will magically sync with what you actually have.